# sql error 'query was empty'

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am not a trained programmer. Whatever I learned is by myself from the net. Please excuse if you find my code and question very amateurish.

I am trying to call matches of buyers against sellers data from the database and automatically mail them their matches.

When I run this code on my system with EasyPhp, it says 'Query was empty". And when I run this on my server, it says `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1 "` where am I going wrong ?

```
<?php

include('adminmaster.htm');

Echo "<center>Mail Matching Properties</center><br><br>";

mysql_connect("localhost", "username","password") or die(mysql_error()); 


mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query= 'SELECT*FROM clientdata WHERE email != "  " AND Transaction="Buyer"';


$result=mysql_query($query);


echo mysql_error();


if (!$result){ die("No Buy results");}

$matchrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($matchrows==0){ die("No Buy results");}


while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))


$Price1= $info['Price']+($info['Price']*10/100);

$Price2 = $info['Price']-($info['Price']*10/100);

$una=$info['username'];

$query2='SELECT*FROM clientdata WHERE email!=" " AND Transaction="Seller"';


$result2=mysql_query($query2);


echo mysql_error();


$matchrows2=mysql_num_rows($result2);


if($matchrows2==0){ die("Sell Data Not Found");}


if(!$result2)

{die("Sell Data Not Found");}

while($info2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))

{

if ($info['Detail']==$info2['Detail'])

{

if ($info['Location']==$info2['Location'])

{

if ($Price1 >= $info2['Price'])
{

if ($Price2 <= $info2['Price'])

{

if ($info['username']!=$info2['username'])

{

echo mysql_error();

echo "<table width=600 border = 1 style='text-align:left';>

<tr>
<td><b>Clients</b></td>
<td><b><font color='maroon'>BUYER</font></b></td>
<td><b><font color='maroon'>SELLER</font></b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Date Posted:</b></td>
<td>$info[Date]</td>
<td>$info2[Date]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Title:</b></td>
<td>$info[propheading]</td>
<td>$info2[propheading]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Transaction:</b></td>
<td>$info[Transaction]</td>
<td>$info2[Transaction]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'><b>Detail:</b></td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info[Detail]</td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info2[Detail]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'><b>Price:</b></td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info[Price]</td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info2[Price]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Additional Data:</b></td>
<td>$info[AdditionalData]</td>
<td>$info2[AdditionalData]</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><b>Location:</b></td>
<td>$info[Location]</td>
<td>$info2[Location]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Agent/Individual:</b></td>
<td>$info[Agent_Ind]</td>
<td>$info2[Agent_Ind]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Name:</b></td>
<td>$info[Title] $info[firstname] $info[lastname]</td>
<td>$info2[Title] $info2[firstname] $info2[lastname]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Phone:</b></td>
<td>$info[Phone]</td>
<td>$info2[Phone]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Email:</b></td>
<td>$info[Email]</td>
<td>$info2[Email]</td></tr>

</table>";

$tomail=$info2['Email'];

if   ($tomail=="anitgopinath@gmail.com"|$tomail=="anit@landshoppe.com"|$tomail=="info@landshoppe.com")  {continue;}

$headers ="From:info@landshoppe.com"."\r\n";

$headers .='Bcc:anit@landshoppe.com'."\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$subject ="You have a Property Match !";

$message="<html></head><body>

<table width=600 border = 1 style='text-align:left';>

<caption><b><font color='maroon'>YOUR PROPERTY MATCH!</font></b></caption>

<tr>
<td><b>Date Posted:</b></td>
<td>$info[Date]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Title:</b></td>
<td>$info[propheading]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Transaction:</b></td>
<td>$info[Transaction]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'><b>Detail:</b></td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info[Detail]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'><b>Price:</b></td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info[Price]</td>
</tr>

<tr><td><b>Additional Data:</b></td><td>$info[AdditionalData]</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Location:</b></td><td>$info[Location]</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Agent/Individual:</b></td><td>$info[Agent_Ind]</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Name:</b></td><td>$info[Title] $info[firstname] $info[lastname]</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Phone:</b></td><td>$info[Phone]</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Email:</b></td><td>$info[Email]</td></tr>

</table></body><html>";

echo $tomail."<br>";
echo "$message"."<br>";

$mailresult=mysql_query(mail($tomail,$subject,$message,$headers));

if ($mailresult){echo "Mailed<br>";}else{echo "Not Mailed !<br>";}

echo "**********************************Seller Match**************************************************<br>";


$tomail2=$info['Email'];

if   ($tomail2=="anitgopinath@gmail.com"|$tomail2=="anit@landshoppe.com"|$tomail2=="info@landshoppe.com"){continue;}

$headers ="From:info@landshoppe.com"."\r\n";

$headers .='Bcc:anit@landshoppe.com'."\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$subject ="You have a Property Match !";

$message="<html></head><body>

<table width=600 border = 1 style='text-align:left';>

<caption><b><font color='maroon'>YOUR PROPERTY MATCH!</font></b></caption>

<tr>
<td><b>Date Posted:</b></td>
<td>$info2[Date]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Title:</b></td>
<td>$info2[propheading]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Transaction:</b></td>
<td>$info2[Transaction]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'><b>Detail:</b></td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info2[Detail]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'><b>Price:</b></td>
<td style='background-color:lightgrey'>$info2[Price]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Additional Data:</b></td>
<td>$info2[AdditionalData]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Location:</b></td>
<td>$info2[Location]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Agent/Individual:</b></td>
<td>$info2[Agent_Ind]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Name:</b></td>
<td>$info2[Title] $info2[firstname] $info2[lastname]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Phone:</b></td>
<td>$info2[Phone]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Email:</b></td>
<td>$info2[Email]</td>
</tr>

</table></body><html>";

echo $tomail2."<br>";
echo "$message"."<br>";

$mailresult2=mysql_query(mail($tomail2,$subject,$message,$headers));

if ($mailresult2){echo "Mailed<br>";}else{echo "Not Mailed !<br>";}

echo "**********************************Buyer Match**************************************************<br>";

}
}
}
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This needs whitespace: `SELECT*FROM`  => `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: @Nanne +1 for typing faster :)

Comment: I tried giving space before and after * but still same...actually it is giving some records in output but I think when it hits the end of the table it is showing "Query Was enmpty"..

Comment: Guys thanks for the prompt responses...got it solved in the mail query part !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when specifying string literals within SQL request you should use single qoutes:

```
$query= "SELECT*FROM clientdata WHERE email != '  ' AND Transaction='Buyer'";
```

Comment: I tried changing to the suggested format..still after the last record is displayed, it still says "Query was empty"...

Comment: Thanks a ton for your prompt response @heximal, the problem has got solved with the mail function

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to sound rude, but you better redesign your code, it's a mess right now. Start with a simple 'divide and conquer' method: mark each block of code that does ONE and only ONE thing - and separate into a single function (leaving only its call in the main script). You'll instantly notice the difference it'll make in both reading and updating your code.

The error you spoke about is caused by this line:

```
$mailresult=mysql_query(mail($tomail,$subject,$message,$headers));
```

... as the result of `mail` function is [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). And when converted into string by mysql_query, it's either an empty string or `'1'`; both of them, of course, are not valid queries. If you need to check the result, it's just...

```
$mailresult=mail($tomail,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

And again, the error itself is simple - but it's hidden in your code so good that five or more SO users failed to find it. ) That's why the code needs restructuring.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code redisgn advice..will definitely learn how to to do that...meanwhile if you will forgive my ignorance, how should the mail query look...?

Comment: Hey I just saw you answer just now...Thanks a ton @raina77ow...I think this should be the problem...will check and revert

Comment: What's "the mail query"? You mean, how do you check the result of function? It's simple: mail() returns true, if the message it tries to send was successfully accepted for delivery by the mail server, false otherwise. By the way, it doesn't mean mail() can check whether the message was actually delivered to its target - or not.

Comment: It worked excellent ! I know that was too stupid a mistake for me to make...and I am gonna really learn restructuring the code ! Thanks a ton again @raina77ow